# Assigning and Summing Numeric value

Tags: javascript

I have created a form using Adobe Acrobat. The form includes 82 questions with five radio buttons each. Each button is named "a" through "e" (e.g., 1a, 1b, 1c, etc.). I need to assign a numerical value to each button:

```
Strongly Disagree = 1 Disagree = 2 Neutral = 3 Agree = 4 Strongly Agree = 5
```

Then, I need to sum each question's numerical value. Logically, the sum function could be expressed as:

```
(1a + 1b + ... + 82e = sum)
```

What's the Java script syntax for this?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why are you asking for Java script syntax in a question tagged "sql"?  I changed the tags.

Comment: Gordon Thank you I did not see that.

Comment: you could store each result in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've got all your values into an array you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the values:

```
var result = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p + c;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aU6ex/)